# Error when Running in Marshmallow Operating System

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, version

Hello Guys I am currently coding a fragment application which has swipe views, however when i try running it to a Marshmallow version of operating system it stops and give error. I think the background has the problem because when i change the image into a image that was created before it runs but when using a new one application got error. i try to run the application in a Lollipop version and there are no errors, been stuck here i really need help, here are my codes

here is the java file

```
package com.example.manginasal.manginasal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.manginasal.manginasal.*;

public class SulitMeals extends Fragment {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sulit_meals, container, false);

        Button smone = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.smonesolo);
        smone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                switch(v.getId()){

                    case R.id.smonesolo:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), SM1.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);//Edited here
                        break;


                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    }
```

and here is the xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0d6636"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/smonesolo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:background="@drawable/smonesolobutton"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/smonedrink"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/smonedrinkbutton"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/smtwosolo"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/smtwosolobutton"/>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/smtwodrink"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
             android:background="@drawable/smtwodrinkbutton"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Main Fragment is here

```
package com.example.manginasal.manginasal;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainMenu extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager pager;
    PagerTabStrip tab_strp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        Category_Adapter mapager=new Category_Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

        pager.setAdapter(mapager);
        tab_strp=(PagerTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tab_strip);
        tab_strp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tab_strp.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here is the xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.manginasal.manginasal.MainMenu" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/tabbackground"
            android:id="@+id/tab_strip"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false">



        </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



</LinearLayout>
```

here is the logcat

```
  08-20 01:21:42.042  14177-14177/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.manginasal.manginasal, PID: 14177
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.manginasal.manginasal.SulitMeals.onCreateView(SulitMeals.java:26)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:535)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17482)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1083)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17482)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17482)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17482)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2594)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17482)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2006)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1171)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1377)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1059)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5804)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5261)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:734)
```

Comment: Your stack trace is cut off part-way through, and the important parts are missing.

Comment: how to fix that? what are the things that i should do? thankyou in advance :)

Comment: "how to fix that?" -- copy the entire stack trace, edit your question, and replace the partial stack trace with the full trace.

Comment: are you referring the logcat?

Comment: i already update it

Comment: as per your stacktrace your variable v is null, before initializing button check wether v is null or not.